# ClassCastException when using DeltaSpike Security?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, cdi, deltaspike

I've written a simple web app to play around with Apache Deltaspike 0.5, but am running into a problem.  The app is a simple JavaEE 6 app, deployed as part of an EAR on JBoss EAP 6.1.  I've declared the Apache Deltaspike Security module interceptor in my beans.xml file, but when I deploy my app I see the following exception:

```
[0m[0m12:41:52,798 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils] (MSC service thread 1-2) class: org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.config.view.ViewConfigExtension activated=true
[0m[31m12:41:52,806 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTestApp.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTestApp.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:341)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:62)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.config.ConfigSourceProvider: Provider org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.DefaultConfigSourceProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.DefaultConfigSourceProvider to org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.config.ConfigSourceProvider
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:438)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ServiceUtils.loadServiceImplementations(ServiceUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.resolveConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:374)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:353)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getAllPropertyValues(ConfigResolver.java:306)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.initConfiguredClassDeactivators(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:152)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.getClassDeactivators(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:143)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.initDeactivatableCacheFor(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.isActivated(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.ConfigurationExtension.init(ConfigurationExtension.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.DefaultConfigSourceProvider to org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.config.ConfigSourceProvider
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3005)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:362)
    ... 34 more

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:62)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more

[0m[0m12:41:52,817 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTestApp.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyTestApp.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

I've Googled around, but can't find any mention of similar errors.  The app itself is based off a simple example app I found in the PicketLink 2.5.1 distribution, so it's not as though I'm doing anything terribly complex.  Any idea what could be causing this or where I could start to look for answers?

Comment: This is text book classloader error. You either have the same jar more than once in your classpath or your application somehow has at least two classloaders and each one loads a different copy of those classes

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  My pom.xml had an error that was causing the libs to be added to both the EAR and the WAR.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Shadowan, would you mind sharing what this error was ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer

This is text book classloader error. You either have the same jar more than once in your classpath or your application somehow has at least two classloaders and each one loads a different copy of those classes